# can't click allow button flash microphone access in chrome extentions

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, flash

I have a chrome extentions to record and upload sound. I embedding some flash content in an iframe to that extention. The flash part is requesting access to the allow the michrophone first. If I open in browser firefox and chrome, it's work proferly. But if open in chrome extentions, allow button is disabled or can't be clicked.

are there any way to fix this?
Thanks......

Comment: Could you please share some code and your manifest file? It will help...

Comment: 80% iframe related question -> solution "all_frames": true

Answer (score 1):

There are security restrictions embedding flash inside a `chrome-extension://` URL, which behaves much like a sandboxed `file://` environment. Perhaps you're running into one.

Here are some bug links for you:

- http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=42796
- http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=58909

A potential workaround is to have an iframe point to an HTTP url with the flash content. You can also make an exception in the flash control panel, but that's per machine and probably not what you want.